# Is there a way to get application name or print root folder name in a view

Tags: codeigniter

Is there a way to get the application name or print root folder name in a view in CodeIgniter?
Actually, I want to print the application in multiple views in CodeIgniter 3.
I tried with base URL but is not a perfect solution when you are using a framework.

Comment: Have a look at https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/reserved_names.html?highlight=apppath and APPPATH,VIEWPATH,BASEPATH. Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

```
FCPATH   -> '/'
BASEPATH -> '/system/'
APPPATH  -> '/application/'
```

**APPPATH** is your application folder

```
echo APPPATH;
```

if you need the root path then **FCPATH.**

```
echo FCPATH;
```

Following are the build-in constants you can use as per your requirements for getting the paths in Codeigniter:

```
EXT: The PHP file extension

FCPATH: Path to the front controller (this file) (root of CI)

SELF: The name of THIS file (index.php)

BASEPATH: Path to the system folder

APPPATH: The path to the “application” folder
```

**Note:-**
For More info regarding this

https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/reserved_names.html?highlight=apppath

Comment: I just want to print application name or root folder name but not application folder path or root path. "APPPATH" giving a full path.

Comment: I just want to print "MyApp" not "E:\wamp64\www\MyApp\" (path) that is given by echo APPPATH;

Answer (score 0):

Get application name or root folder name I used [codeigniter reserved name](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/reserved_names.html) in a [php basename function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php).

```
echo FCPATH;
// output: E:\wamp64\www\MyApplicationName\

echo basename(FCPATH);
// output: MyApplicationName
```